# Partition key string in dynamoDB Java

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a method in java for DynamoDB to get the name of the partition key given a table? In other words, I want a method that will return a string of the partition key name for a table. I can't seem to find this. Thanks.

Comment: In future, please do a little more research on your own before posting.  I have NEVER used DynamoDB but it took me less than 5 minutes to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The partition key is in the response to the `DescribeTable` action, in the `KeySchema` section. It's the attribute with `KeyType: HASH`.

See [Getting Information About a Table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.GetTableInfo.html).  In the example, the response is

```
{
  "Table": {
    "AttributeDefinitions": [
      {
        "AttributeName": "Artist",
        "AttributeType": "S"
      },
      {
        "AttributeName": "SongTitle",
        "AttributeType": "S"
      }
    ],
    "TableName": "Music",
    "KeySchema": [
      {
        "AttributeName": "Artist",
        "KeyType": "HASH"  //Partition key <<<<<<=============
      },
      {
        "AttributeName": "SongTitle",
        "KeyType": "RANGE"  //Sort key
      }
    ],

    ...
}
```